# Removes all after the first block of numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write code that removes all after the first block of numbers and text.Do you have any idea how to do this.

```
string = '009EPMT18$MBS'
```

the expected result

```
string = '009EPMT'
```

Comment: Read about [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [Regex replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) in JS

Comment: You should post the JavaScript that you're tried.

Comment: '009EPMT18$MBS'.match(/\d+/)[0] I tried with reg exp, but this code return only 009

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You were on the right track, the letters were just missing from your pattern:

```
var s = '009EPMT18$MBS';
var result;

var m = s.match(/^\d+[A-Z]+/); // first numbers and uppercase text
if (m) result = m[0]; // result = "009EPMT"
```

Regex explanation: beginning of string `^` followed by 1 or more digits `\d+` followed by 1 or more letters from A to Z `[A-Z]+`. Note that lowercase characters will not match.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need regex to do that. It's a string analysis syntax common in many languages. There are many regular expressions which would do what you want, here's one:

`var myRegex = /^[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+/;`

`^` means that the search must begin at the start of the string.
`[0-9]` means that right after the beginning, there must be characters in the 0 to 9 range.
`+` means there must be one or more of the previous condition, meaning there must be one or more digits.
`[a-zA-Z]` means there must be any character in the range a to z or A to Z. This won't include accented characters and letters from other alphabets though.

Calling `.exec(string)` on a regex returns an array of found strings in the passed string.